# PHP SQL Clear duplicates from query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Been trying for a few hours now to get the distinct function to work with this sql code and its just doesnt seem to want to work, so I need help.

`SELECT * FROM uni WHERE name LIKE (:keyword) ORDER BY name ASC LIMIT 0, 15`

Comment: What's "work"? Which columns are you trying to pull from `uni`?

Comment: Why the `()`'s around `:keyword`? And, `SELECT DISTINCT ..`  should normally do the trick, for, well, distinct results.

Comment: Remove the ( ) in the query, if don't work paste your php code.

Comment: its for a json recommendations thing like the way google change the li list under the search box and i seem to have gotten it.SELECT DISTINCT uni FROM nameWHERE uni LIKE (:keyword) ORDER BY uni ASC LIMIT 0, 15
it

Answer (score 0):

Got it,

Its for a google style json recommendations that changes when you enter in different items

`SELECT DISTINCT uni FROM name WHERE uni LIKE (:keyword) ORDER BY uni ASC LIMIT 0, 15`